# Building a Regex for Shipping Comments

Tags: php, regex, fedex, usps

```
Shipped 1-95080 via other USPS with tracking 1Z2216FE0348543895.

Shipped 1-95080 via other FedEx with tracking 729870539581, 729870539592.
```

Here are two separate "comments" or pieces of data that are entered into an individual orders comment data.

I need to search the comment data for the "carrier" and the individual tracking numbers but their formats vary in format depending on the carrier.

We only use 2 shipping carriers USPS and FedEx for package tracking. I want to create a function to extract the carrier type and extract just the tracking numbers from these comments to place them into individual places in our database for future use. I just hate regular expressions.

Does anyone have anything that might point me in the right direction? (Also this is all in PHP)

Comment: As you hate the wonderful regex, you haven't any try yet to show? Not clear if `729870539581, 729870539592` should be two seperate matches. Maybe something basic will do already: [`\b(USPS|FedEx)\b with tracking (.*?)\.`](https://regex101.com/r/JEjjuL/1). See [this PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##dY/Pa8IwHMXv@Su@h0GT0ZW0NTNhzl6M82Zpt8sohKrVhPkjxDg9iP96tZ6GsMuDB4/Pe89q27aDLJ/kCD3tvYN3CEptrG0WEL8IRjmFX1PDzuvGwVeZl3A0XoN39fzHbFcQfydJ/DqWNO1x1ku5YBH6HzBuFvL0QOgngvcpSwXjcfjHiSQK3hAyS2xds1Kb2s@1qtdrHFyqGe6mnO84Us0eiDh6zkgVXYIQuk833R18CHkhP1QpP9W0GMmCwBAoQQDWma1XDnchcivMhm17BQ).

Comment: See [this PHP demo](https://tio.run/##fZBfb4IwFMXf@RT3gQRwHX9lQpyaJWPb24hsL1NDChZpBCG1ui2bfnUGTUyM2fbSpD3n/O49rfO6aW4n4VMoSfKWMxiBEuW0rskSrGvfNT0T9hRDxXPC4DUKI3inPAfOcLqmmxVYb7Zt3TwEptP33L7j@a4u/Q14IMvg44IwsH1vYLqO73oWOrv59n@kX1bBSYrAsh0EkFUVSjADXRm2vRjpah3nidqlvsUS2jy5iKt6b6JBb64faZeimVozsopLzNM8xkWhthwE3Se1Z7XjCMJp8BhHwUv8PL0PphqMwdSkL6kbzwhOc7WzwV0E8hpGY5D3Wqt1OoBhACNltSfQtoFsVxQgBoFsCh0zhj/jbU4zLigzeb3QhkI65bd1QTnQDNKqLLF4PTln1qJtLNYXLlUxZggWV4aCzj0CeJAEsmZ0w2MmhrXvh6b5AQ) for getting multiple comma separated matches with this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read you said that hate regexp, but it could be useful to this case.
I wrote an example that could help you.

To the first phrase:

```
<?php
$string = 'Shipped 1-95080 via other USPS with tracking 1Z2216FE0348543895.';
preg_match('/.+(?P<ship_num>\d{1}\-\d+).+via other (?P<company>\w+) with tracking (?<tracking_code>[\w,\s]+)/', $string, $match);

if(strpos($match['tracking_code'], ',')!==false) {
    $match['tracking_code'] = array_map(function($index) {
        return trim($index);
    }, explode(',', $match['tracking_code']));
}

echo $match['ship_num']; // this echo prints '1-95080'
echo $match['company']; // this echo prints 'USPS'
print_r($match['tracking_code']); // this print_r prints an array with the value '1Z2216FE0348543895'

?>
```

And the second one:

```
<?php
$string = 'Shipped 1-95080 via other FedEx with tracking 729870539581, 729870539592.';
preg_match('/.+(?P<ship_num>\d{1}\-\d+).+via other (?P<company>\w+) with tracking (?<tracking_code>[\w,\s]+)/', $string, $match);

if(strpos($match['tracking_code'], ',')!==false) {
    $match['tracking_code'] = array_map(function($index) {
        return trim($index);
    }, explode(',', $match['tracking_code']));
}

echo $match['ship_num']; // this echo prints '1-95080'
echo $match['company']; // this echo prints 'FedEx'
print_r($match['tracking_code']); // this print_r prints an array with the values '729870539581' and '729870539592'

?>
```

This RegExp will catch 3 groups:

`(?P<ship_num>\d{1}\-\d+)`
This group will catch one number(`\d`), one hyphen(`\-`) and some numbers(`\d+`).

`(?P<company>\w+)`
This group will catch just some alphabetical characters(`\w+`).

`(?<tracking_code>[\w,\s]+)`
Finally, this group will catch some spaces characters(`\s`), commas and alphabetical characters(`\w`).

In those all groups, I named each of them(`?P<group name>`).

The tool [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) could be useful to test RegExp.

Answer (score 2):

If the format is always the same, you could probably us a combination of [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Considering your comments will always have either 'USPS' or 'FedEx' in the string, just use a condition with strpos().  In these kinds of situations, you might want to use [strtoupper()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) just to make sure the case matches:

```
if (strpos(strtoupper($yourCommentString), 'USPS') !== false)
    $carrier = 'USPS';
else
    $carrier = 'FedEx';
```

As for the tracking numbers, I found a solution that doesn't require regex, assuming the numbers are always following 'tracking ' and separated by ', ':

```
$string = 'Shipped 1-95080 via other USPS with tracking 1Z2216FE0348543895, 1Z2216FE0348543895';

$start = strpos($string, 'tracking ') + strlen('tracking ');
$trackString = substr($string, $start);

$allTrack = explode(', ', $trackString);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working for determining carrier, I came up with something like this using strstr. I'm just trying to figure out the tracking numbers themselves now.

Comment: Excellent this will work, according to my DB every single message will follow that format. A very smart simple approach.